# Javascript - for-of loop crashing when trying to loop through an object

Tags: javascript, for-of-loop

I have this object passed in by a function

[image]

and then I want to loop through it with this code

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    let item = {};
    let i = 0;
    for (item of files) {
        formData.append('file' + i, files[i]);
        formData.append('filesNumber', i + 1);
        i++;
    }
```

but when the execution reaches the declaration of the for loop, it crashes with this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: files[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
```

What is wrong?

Comment: what is `FormData`?

Comment: @NinaScholz https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: You can use a simple index-based for loop to iterate over `files`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Comment: What is the type of `files` ?

Comment: it says it in the screenshot, its just an object {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic objects do not automatically implement `Symbol.iterator`. [Here's a list of objects that do.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

In order to use the `for..of` syntax, you'll have to implement your own iterator.

```js
let files = {
  0: "a",
  1: "b",
  2: "c",
  
  [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
    let i = 0;
    while (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      yield this[i];
      i++;
    }
  }
};

for (let item of files) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

Alternatively, you just [grabs the objects keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and iterate over them.

```js
let files = {
  0: "a",
  1: "b",
  2: "c"
};

let keys = Object.keys(files);
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  let key = keys[i];
  let item = files[key];
  console.log(`${key}: ${item}`);
}
```

You can also use the good, old-fashioned [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to go over the keys.

```js
let files = {
  0: "a",
  1: "b",
  2: "c"
};

for (let key in files) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${files[key]}`);
}
```

Comment: but what does FormData has to do with anything, it crashes at the for-loop statement

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer I misread your question. What is the type of `files`? You don't show where you get that object.

Comment: it says it in the screenshot, its just an object {}